# Multiple search types - node.js - express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, curl, express, get

I get this method to search through "_id" I want to look further through the name and category. How should I implement the method?

This is my method to search "_id":

```
//GET
app.get("/:id", function(req, res, next) {
    req.collection.findOne({
        _id: id(req.params.id)
    }, function(e, result) {
        if(e) return next(e);
        res.send(result);
    });
});
```

Comment: How you pass the name and category?

Comment: @adricadar I had thought put in the URL like this: for "id" -> "/id/:id" for "name" -> "/name/:name", and have a method for each search. Do you think that would be the solution?

Comment: it's a solution, but depends of what you want to achieve. you can add /:id/:name and use same method

Comment: I want to search for several different types (name, id, sku), I can not use the same method that I look for each type in the corresponding column in my database, right?

Comment: Did you succeed with the solution? If you search for same object that have this property you can search in the same method, but this depends on your bussines logic.